# ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape data from an .idx file and import the data into the table I created in SQL.

```
for row in content:
    if len(row)!= 0:
            row = row.strip('\n')
            if str(row).endswith(".txt"):
                columns = row.split("|")
                #print(columns)
                cik = columns[0]
                companyname = columns[1]
                formtype = columns[2]
                datefield = columns[3]
                filenames = columns[4]
                
                query= "INSERT class.firmsreports (cik, companyname, formtype, datefiled, filenames) VALUES ('%(1)s', '%(2)s', '%(3)s', '%(4)s', %(5)s)" %{"1": cik, "2": companyname, "3": formtype, "4": datefiled, "5": filenames};
                #print(query)
                cursor.execute(query)
                database.commit()
```

This is my code and im getting this error: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'txt)' at line 1. Any tips on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use pre3pared statements with an tuple, and so youz need only once to thefine the query string

Your table firmsreports  must have those exacte five columns with he **same** names cik, companyname, formtype, datefiled, filenames in it.

```
query= "INSERT class.firmsreports (cik, companyname, formtype, datefiled, filenames) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" ;
for row in content:
    if len(row)!= 0:
            row = row.strip('\n')
            if str(row).endswith(".txt"):
                columns = row.split("|")
                #print(query)
                cursor.execute(query,(columns[0],columns[1],columns[2],columns[3]columns[4]))
                database.commit()
```

Comment: I feel dumb, when I made the table the column was "filename" and for the rest of the code i was using "filenames" thank you. i got it to work

Comment: that happens, sometimes there are invisible characters, which make it quite difficult to spot